# Assigning View to ContentControl in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, contentcontrol

I have a set of `ViewModel` each represented a feature and each ViewModel is associated with a View. And I have a `MainWindow` in which I should display the View as and when an a ViewModel associated with it is created. How should o do this?

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<FlowLayoutControl>
    <ContentControl Name="MainScreen">
    </ContentControl>
</FlowLayoutControl>
```

I have a vieModel Test1 and Test2 each having its own datatemplate. Now, I want to set the `ContentControl` to one of the viewmodel when I need it. How do I do this?

Comment: Did you create separate ViewModel for the MainWindow with these feature ViewModels as properties in them?

Answer (score 2):

If your `DataTemplate` in Resources looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel}">
...
```

When you need use `ContentControl` as:

```
<ContentControl Name="MyContent">            
    <local:ViewModel /> <!-- Your ViewModel here -->
</ContentControl>
```

This means, that the DataTemplate will be used explicitly for all Controls of this type.

If for your `DataTemplate` set *`x:Key`*:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel}">
...
```

When you need use `ContentControl` like this:

```
<ContentControl Name="MyContent"  
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}">

    <local:ViewModel /> <!-- Your ViewModel here -->
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: @harin04: My answer helped you?

Comment: @harin04: Okay, you can ignore me. But next time, I will not help you.

Comment: You helped others :)